# storing a value of a column but not its index, and datatype

Tags: python, pandas

Using a value of a column and assigning that value to store all similar kind of values to it.

df1 :

```
user gender age rating
a   ma  young   PG
b   fe  young   PG
c   ma  adult   PG
d   fe  adult   PG
e   ma  young   PG
f   fe  young   PG
```

df2:

```
gender  age rating
ma  young   PG
fe  young   PG
ma  adult   PG
fe  adult   PG
ma  young   PG
fe  young   PG
```

When I apply the following:

```
aa = df.loc[df['user'] == 'b']
mm = aa['age']
print(mm)
```

I obtain:

```
2 young
name: age, dtype: object.
```

However, when I try this:

```
mem_data = df2[df2['age'] == mm]
```

error :

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

expected output:

```
gender  age rating
ma  young   PG
fe  young   PG
ma  young   PG
fe  young   PG
```

I want `mm` to only store 'young'.

Answer (score 0):

```
aa = df.user[df['user'] == 'b']
```

instead of using this

```
mm = aa['age']
```

I used

```
mm = df.age[df.user ='b'].iloc[0]
```

Thanks